# python3 ImportError: No module named 'numpy' on windows10

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I have a problem with importing the 'numpy' package in python.
I'm currently using python3.4.5 in anaconda3. But when I try to run the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/SourceCodes/PycharmSources/trial/titanic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 32, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Well, I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the numpy and pandas libraries using both the

```
pip uninstall numpy / pip insatll numpy
conda install -f numpy
```

commands, but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you got multiple Python versions installed?

Comment: yeah, I happen to have both python 3.6.1 and 3.4.5.. Could that be causing the problem? I'm using pyCharm and have selected 3.4.5 as my project interpreter by the way..

Comment: You should install it specifically for the python version you are currently running. Or, even better, use a python venv.

Comment: Yeah you could be installing numpy for one version and then using the other.

Comment: You can see a list of packages installed in Pycharm, and can also easily install them as well

Comment: Well in fact, Pycharm is the very first channel that I used to install those packages. And I can see that 'numpy' is already installed for my project interpreter in the list. If that's the case, maybe having dual pythons isn't causing the problem?

Comment: Okay, so I changed the project interpreter and it's now working.. I see the 'numpy' package installed in both interpreters' environment but I don't understand why one is working and the other isn't. Thanks both of you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674375/1083292)

After trying many suggestions from various sites and similar questions, what worked for me was to uninstall all Python stuff and reinstall Anaconda only. The previous Python installation I had was not only redundant but only caused me trouble.